# ggplot2 summarySE plotting small data set - missing points using geom_point

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I am working with a small data set as follows:

```
Thermo  Chl     Month
1.53    1.53    May
3.63    1.53    June
3.83    2.33    July
3.84    2.33    July
5.08           August
5.50           August
5.04    1.55    September
5.90    1.70    September
3.75           September
3.63    1.70    September
5.90    1.70    September
9.00    2.50    October
11.03   1.03    October
11.00   1.00    October
9.00    2.37    October
9.00    2.03    November
14.96   2.04    November
7.13    15.95   January
13.03   9.00    February
9.00    1.03    April
9.00    2.50    May
8.97    2.50    May
4.88    2.50    June
4.88    2.50    June
3.63    2.50    July
4.88    1.03    July
3.83    2.33    August
5.53    2.30    August
7.20    2.37    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.20    2.37    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.17    1.08    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.17    1.03    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.17    1.03    September
9.00    1.03    October
9.00    2.37    October
8.97    5.50    October
11.00   5.50    October
13.00   10.00   November
13.00   10.00   December
11.00   15.17   January
11.00   1.03    February
9.00    2.33    March
5.50    1.03    April
3.83    2.37    May
3.87    2.33    June
5.50    3.83    June
3.83    2.33    July
5.50    3.37    July
7.17    2.37    July
7.17    2.30    August
7.17    2.33    September
9.00    2.33    September
9.03    3.83    September
9.00    3.83    September
9.00    2.33    September
9.00    2.37    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.17    4.00    September
7.17    3.50    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.20    2.33    September
7.17    3.83    September
7.17    2.33    October
7.17    2.30    October
7.17    2.33    October
7.17    2.33    October
8.68    2.33    October
7.20    2.33    October
9.00    3.87    October
9.00    5.50    October
11.00   5.50    November
13.00   1.03    November
11.00   3.83    November
9.00    3.83    December
6.03    13.00   March
8.00    15.67   March
5.97    0.70    April
5.57    2.40    May
7.25    1.03    May
5.50    2.33    June
5.50    3.00    July
4.70    2.00    July
5.50    2.33    August
5.50    2.33    August
9.00    2.33    September
9.00    1.03    September
9.00    2.33    September
7.13    2.37    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.17    2.43    September
7.20    1.07    September
7.17    2.00    September
7.17    2.33    September
7.17    2.00    September
7.17    1.03    September
7.13    2.33    October
7.17    2.33    October
7.17    2.30    October
7.17    2.33    October
9.00    3.83    October
13.00   2.33    October
14.97   3.83    October
14.93   2.03    October
```

When I plot with the summarySE and ggplot2 functions as follows:

```
phyto.maxchl$Month <- factor(phyto.maxchl$Month)

phyto.se <- summarySE(phyto.maxchl, measurevar="Thermocline", groupvars=c("Month"))

ggplot(phyto.se, aes(x=phyto.se$Month, y=phyto.se$Thermocline)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(),stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=phyto.se$Thermocline-se, ymax=phyto.se$Thermocline+se),
                width=.2,            
                position=position_dodge(.9))+
  ylab("Thermocline Depth (m)")+
  xlab("Month")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=70,size=15,vjust=0.60))+
  labs(title = "Thermocline Depth for 2013 - 2016")+
  scale_y_continuous(trans='reverse')+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

I am missing points for January - April. Is this because I don't have enough data points to satisfy the requirements needed to calculate standard error?

Comment: The columns names used in `summarySE` differs from those in the `df`. Also, don't use `$` inside `aes()`

Answer (score 1):

`summarySE()` returns `NA` if it encounters any `NA` inside a group, unless `na.rm = TRUE` is supplied as argument.

```
Rmisc::summarySE(df, "Chl", groupvars="Month")
#>        Month  N       Chl        sd        se         ci
#> 1      April  3  0.920000 0.1905256 0.1100000  0.4732918
#> 2     August  7        NA        NA        NA         NA
#> 3   December  2  6.915000 4.3628488 3.0850000 39.1986416
#> 4   February  2  5.015000 5.6356410 3.9850000 50.6342259
#> 5    January  2 15.560000 0.5515433 0.3900000  4.9554198
#> 6       July  9  2.362222 0.6471626 0.2157209  0.4974532
#> 7       June  6  2.503333 0.7439803 0.3037287  0.7807594
#> 8      March  3 10.333333 7.0584866 4.0752191 17.5342528
#> 9        May  6  2.055000 0.6229848 0.2543325  0.6537824
#> 10  November  6  4.071667 3.3103318 1.3514373  3.4739802
#> 11   October 24  2.747083 1.2873312 0.2627754  0.5435923
#> 12 September 42        NA        NA        NA         NA
```

As opposed to:

```
Rmisc::summarySE(df, "Chl", groupvars="Month", na.rm = T)
#>        Month  N       Chl         sd          se          ci
#> 1      April  3  0.920000 0.19052559 0.110000000  0.47329180
#> 2     August  5  2.318000 0.01643168 0.007348469  0.02040262
#> 3   December  2  6.915000 4.36284884 3.085000000 39.19864161
#> 4   February  2  5.015000 5.63564105 3.985000000 50.63422587
#> 5    January  2 15.560000 0.55154329 0.390000000  4.95541985
#> 6       July  9  2.362222 0.64716261 0.215720870  0.49745322
#> 7       June  6  2.503333 0.74398029 0.303728680  0.78075943
#> 8      March  3 10.333333 7.05848662 4.075219149 17.53425280
#> 9        May  6  2.055000 0.62298475 0.254332460  0.65378240
#> 10  November  6  4.071667 3.31033181 1.351437301  3.47398018
#> 11   October 24  2.747083 1.28733118 0.262775376  0.54359228
#> 12 September 41  2.246098 0.75104220 0.117293086  0.23705817
```

That's why you get two missing values. The fact that the `NA`s are relative to January and April as opposed to the correct August and September is probably because of a discrepancy between the `Month` factor values and its labels.

```
levels(df$Month) <- month.name
```

or

```
df$Month <- factor(df$Month, levels = month.name)
```

should fix it.

Following is your exact code, whithout `NA`s and some fixes at the `gggplot` call. In particular you should never use `df$Var` inside a `aes()`, the name of the variable is enough.

```
df2 <- Rmisc::summarySE(df, "Chl", groupvars="Month", na.rm = T)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df2, aes(x=factor(Month, levels = month.name), y=Chl)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(),stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Chl-se, ymax=Chl+se),
                width=.2,            
                position=position_dodge(.9))+
  ylab("Thermocline Depth (m)")+
  xlab("Month")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=70,size=15,vjust=0.60))+
  labs(title = "Thermocline Depth for 2013 - 2016")+
  scale_y_continuous(trans='reverse')+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
#> Warning: Width not defined. Set with `position_dodge(width = ?)`
```

[image]

Just for completeness, I'll show you how is not even necessary to calculate the summary beforehand, and we can leave the calculation to `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(df, aes(factor(Month, levels = month.name), Chl)) +
  stat_summary(geom = 'point', position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  stat_summary(geom = 'errorbar', width=.2,            
               position=position_dodge(.9))+
  ylab("Thermocline Depth (m)")+
  xlab("Month")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=70,size=15,vjust=0.60))+
  labs(title = "Thermocline Depth for 2013 - 2016")+
  scale_y_continuous(trans='reverse')+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'Thermo  Chl     Month
1.53    1.53    May
             3.63    1.53    June
             3.83    2.33    July
             3.84    2.33    July
             5.08     NA      August
             5.50     NA      August
             5.04    1.55    September
             5.90    1.70    September
             3.75     NA      September
             3.63    1.70    September
             5.90    1.70    September
             9.00    2.50    October
             11.03   1.03    October
             11.00   1.00    October
             9.00    2.37    October
             9.00    2.03    November
             14.96   2.04    November
             7.13    15.95   January
             13.03   9.00    February
             9.00    1.03    April
             9.00    2.50    May
             8.97    2.50    May
             4.88    2.50    June
             4.88    2.50    June
             3.63    2.50    July
             4.88    1.03    July
             3.83    2.33    August
             5.53    2.30    August
             7.20    2.37    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.20    2.37    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.17    1.08    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.17    1.03    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.17    1.03    September
             9.00    1.03    October
             9.00    2.37    October
             8.97    5.50    October
             11.00   5.50    October
             13.00   10.00   November
             13.00   10.00   December
             11.00   15.17   January
             11.00   1.03    February
             9.00    2.33    March
             5.50    1.03    April
             3.83    2.37    May
             3.87    2.33    June
             5.50    3.83    June
             3.83    2.33    July
             5.50    3.37    July
             7.17    2.37    July
             7.17    2.30    August
             7.17    2.33    September
             9.00    2.33    September
             9.03    3.83    September
             9.00    3.83    September
             9.00    2.33    September
             9.00    2.37    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.17    4.00    September
             7.17    3.50    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.20    2.33    September
             7.17    3.83    September
             7.17    2.33    October
             7.17    2.30    October
             7.17    2.33    October
             7.17    2.33    October
             8.68    2.33    October
             7.20    2.33    October
             9.00    3.87    October
             9.00    5.50    October
             11.00   5.50    November
             13.00   1.03    November
             11.00   3.83    November
             9.00    3.83    December
             6.03    13.00   March
             8.00    15.67   March
             5.97    0.70    April
             5.57    2.40    May
             7.25    1.03    May
             5.50    2.33    June
             5.50    3.00    July
             4.70    2.00    July
             5.50    2.33    August
             5.50    2.33    August
             9.00    2.33    September
             9.00    1.03    September
             9.00    2.33    September
             7.13    2.37    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.17    2.43    September
             7.20    1.07    September
             7.17    2.00    September
             7.17    2.33    September
             7.17    2.00    September
             7.17    1.03    September
             7.13    2.33    October
             7.17    2.33    October
             7.17    2.30    October
             7.17    2.33    October
             9.00    3.83    October
             13.00   2.33    October
             14.97   3.83    October
             14.93   2.03    October', h = TRUE)
```